# pygame - invalid character in identifier

Tags: python, pygame

I am getting the above mentioned error on executing this code . This is a example to understand the clock in pygame. Any suggestions how to remove this  error

[image: This is the image of the error occuring in VS code]

Here is the code

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
def myquit():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit(0)
  
def main():
    # Initialize Pygame
    pygame.init()
  
    # Set up screen
    SCREEN_WIDTH = 600
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480
    window = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Game Clock') # Set the window bar title
    screen = pygame.display.get_surface() # This is where images are displayed
  
    # Set up font
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
  
    # Set up clock
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 30
    seconds = 0
    pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT + 1, 1000) # Used to correctly implement seconds
  
    while True: # for each frame
        clock.tick(FPS)
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))       
        time_display = font.render("Time: " + str(clock.get_time()), 1, (0, 0, 0))
        rawtime_display = font.render("Raw Time: " + str(clock.get_rawtime()), 1, (0, 0, 0))
        fps_display = font.render("FPS: " + str(clock.get_fps()), 1, (0, 0, 0))
        pygame_total_ticks_display = font.render("Pygame Ticks (total): " + str(pygame.time.get_ticks()), 1, (0, 0, 0))
        seconds_display = font.render("Seconds: " + str(seconds), 1, (0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(time_display, (10, 10))
        screen.blit(rawtime_display, (10, 35))
        screen.blit(fps_display, (10, 60))
        screen.blit(pygame_total_ticks_display, (10, 85))
        screen.blit(seconds_display, (10, 110))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                quit()
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    myquit()
            elif event.type == USEREVENT + 1:
                seconds+=1
        pygame.display.flip()
  
main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete and re**type** the line. You probably have some non-printable whitespace in there like zero_width_space that messes up the name. You can get those characters in there by copy and pasting code from websites.